# Puma Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor> in puma.rb config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

When I run puma, I'm getting this error:

```
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `select'
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `handle_servers'
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:360:in `block in run'
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `select'
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `handle_servers'
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:360:in `block in run'
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `select'
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `handle_servers'
/Users/my_account/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:360:in `block in run'
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
```

My puma.rb file:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'

on_restart do
  puts "Puma restarting..."
end

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
log_dir = "#{app_dir}/log"

puts "LOG DIR: #{log_dir}"

if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  stdout_redirect "#{log_dir}/puma.stdout.log", "#{log_dir}/puma.stderr.log", true
end

Causes problem
on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end

Causes problem
preload_app!
```

This issue is caused by the puma.rb config file. I was uncommenting each line to see if any of them would work but it seems like having any line of code in the puma.rb file just causes the `Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor` error.

Comment: Two quick guesses: 1) another server instance is running in the background; 2) you're using a port number that requires an administrator level access (`sudo`). For example, trying to run Puma on port 80 will throw errors unless you have admin privileges.

Comment: I wasn't sure but thought it was my puma.rb config file. Commented it out and works with the defaults. I think some of the settings have changed.

Comment: Consider editing the question - add the `puma.rb` configuration file so we could help track down the cause.

Answer (score 1):

If you use capistrano, you need to comment preload_app!
try to use phased-restart instead restart

I've solved this issue with the following changes in the puma.rb (config file). In my case, I use capistrano to deploy and restart puma. The are 2 requirements to use the command **phased-restart**: workers >= 2 and don't use preload

```
workers 2
#preload_app!
```

My restart command (**phased-restart**):

`pumactl -S /srv/apps/my_app/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F /srv/apps/my_app/shared/config/puma.rb phased-restart`

Comment: I had to update my `puma` gem from `4.x` to `5.x` and then removed `preload_app!` from `config/puma.rb`.

Comment: FYI, `preload_app` is automatically used in `puma` 5+ when `workers` is >= 2.